# Getting Async Await Error and blank value in Array

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, array.prototype.map

I am getting the below error:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Also I got the blank array "console.log(userTasklist)".

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
    // create the connection to database
    const connection = async ()=> { 
        return await mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'whosin'
        })
    }
exports.allUserList = async (req, res) => {
    const db = await connection()
    let userID = req.params.userid;    
    
    const userdata = await db.query('SELECT name, user_id, employee_code FROM users WHERE under_gh = ?', [userID]);
    //console.log(userdata[0])
    
        if (userdata[0] && userdata[0].length > 0) {
            let userTasklist = [];
            userdata[0].map((datauser) => {
                var objtask = {};
                const taskdata =  await db.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as created_date, created_time, tasklist, user_id, DATE_FORMAT(created_by, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, DATE_FORMAT(created_by, '%H:%i:%s') as time FROM tasklist where user_id = ?", [datauser.user_id]);
               
                    if (taskdata[0] && taskdata[0].length > 0) {
                        objtask = {
                            userid: datauser.user_id,
                            tasklist: taskdata[0]
                        }
                        console.log(objtask);
                        userTasklist.push(objtask);
                    }
                
            })
            console.log(userTasklist)
            //res.send({ message: "user list fetched", userdata: userdata[0], tasklistdata: userTasklist })
        }   
}
```

Comment: `userdata[0].map((datauser) => {` is not async and you are using `await db.query(....` inside of it.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson...... So how I will add async on userdata[0].map((datauser) => {

I am new in Node. Please Suggest

Comment: Now I am using this..... userdata[0].map(async (datauser) => {
Still  console.log(userTasklist)   this array is blank

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the wait for the db.query is within the map function. The map function needs to have the async keyword. However, it still will not work unless you wrap it in a Promise.all. This will make sure all the map iterations are resolved before moving forward in your code.

```
exports.allUserList = async (req, res) => {
  const db = await connection()
  let userID = req.params.userid

  const userdata = await db.query('SELECT name, user_id, employee_code FROM users WHERE under_gh = ?', [userID])
  // console.log(userdata[0])

  if (userdata[0] && userdata[0].length > 0) {
    let userTasklist = []
    await Promise.all(
      userdata[0].map(async (datauser) => {
        var objtask = {}
        const taskdata = await db.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as created_date, created_time, tasklist, user_id, DATE_FORMAT(created_by, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, DATE_FORMAT(created_by, '%H:%i:%s') as time FROM tasklist where user_id = ?", [datauser.user_id])

        if (taskdata[0] && taskdata[0].length > 0) {
          objtask = {
            userid: datauser.user_id,
            tasklist: taskdata[0]
          }
          console.log(objtask)
          userTasklist.push(objtask)
        }
      })
    )

    console.log(userTasklist)
    // res.send({ message: "user list fetched", userdata: userdata[0], tasklistdata: userTasklist })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `userdata[0].map((datauser) => {` to `userdata[0].map(async (datauser) => {`

Comment: Now I am using this..... userdata[0].map(async (datauser) => { Still console.log(userTasklist) this array is blank